# Multiple images for an option?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using select2. I've manage to add image to an option using templating. But now I want to add more then one image per option and can't figure it out what is the best solution for doing that.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     function format(state) {
         var originalOption = state.element;

         return state.text + "<img src='images/filters/" + $(originalOption).data('foo') + ".png'  width='30px' height='30px' />";
     }

     $('.consultant-select').select2({
         allowClear: true,
         maximumSelectionSize: 1,
         formatResult: format,
         formatSelection: format,
         escapeMarkup: function (m) {
             return m;
         }
     });
 });
```

Here is my code from jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/emilium/ctdk42xb/.

Comment: If you just add more `<img>`s, you get more images

Comment: But then each option will have the same number of images. Is it a good solution to use multiple data-* for each image?

Comment: not really sure what the goal is, but yes, you can have as many data-* attributes as you want.

Comment: Each option has two or three icons.I want to use only one data-*. (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use semicolons to separate the names of the icons.

The `data-foo` attributes would look like:

```
data-foo="icon1;icon2;icon3"
```

And the `format()` function would look like:

```
function format(state) {
    var text = state.text;
    $.each($(state.element).data('foo').split(';'), function(i, icon) {
        text += '<img src="images/filters/' + icon + '.png" width="30" height="30" />';
    }
    return text;
}
```

Comment: After the edit from     `$.each(state.element.data('foo').split(';'), function(i, icon)`   to `$.each($(state.element).data('foo').split(';'), function(i, icon)` is working like a charm. Great thanks!